# emacs 26.1 "Symbol’s function definition is void: bibtex-completion-candidates-formatter"

Tags: debugging, helm-bibtex

I have updated to Emacs 26.1. and reinstalled all packages. When running `helm-bibtex`, the bibliographies are loaded, but then the process terminates with the following error message:

`helm-bibtex-candidates-formatter: Symbol’s function definition is void: bibtex-completion-candidates-formatter`

Can anyone give me a hint what might cause this problem? I am using `helm-bibtex` 2.0.0 and `bibtex-completion` 20211019.1306, both from MELPA.

Answer (score 0):

`helm-bibtex 2.0.0` is five years old. The variable`bibtex-completion-candidates-formatter` was removed in 2016. Updating to the current version on Melpa, 20210725.1510, should fix this problem.